# Преобразовать строка дата в. long

Tags: java, android

Есть Api в котором респонс даты в таком виде "date": "Mon, 11 Sep 2017 16:59:55 GMT". при реквесте дата должна быть такая "date": 1262307723.
когда юзаю date = new Date().getTime() результат такой date = 1505150434291. 
Вопрос такой, какой формат даты использовать, чтобы получить данный формат date": 1262307723

Comment: Обычно в документации API описано, в каком формате данные ожидаются.

Answer (score 2):

`new Date("Mon, 11 Sep 2017 16:59:55 GMT").getTime()` вернёт значение времени вплоть до миллисекунд, в этом числе будет 13 знаков. 
А в числе `1262307723` знаков 10, здесь время только с точностью до секунд.

Поделите результат от `new Date(...).getTime()` на 1000 и получите то, что нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Это [Epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

В вашем случае 1262307723 = пятница, 1 января 2010 г., 04:02:03 GMT+03:00
Получить можно например так

```
System.currentTimeMillis()/1000
```

Но вообще лучше посмотреть в документацию к вашему API.

Comment: спасибо,помогло

Comment: @antonruban, пожалуйста. Если ответ помог, то можно его "принять".